# Adding SAPUI5 plug in to Eclipse Juno / error

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to add SAPUi5 plug in to eclipse Juno.
From this link [: [http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:1080/repository/drop/][1]](http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:1080/repository/drop/%5d%5b1%5d) I have downloaded "sapui5-dist-1.18.0-release.zip " to my local computer and unzipped it.
then I went to eclipse -> help -> download new software. 
I am getting the following error and I am not sure where went wrong here

"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: SAPUI5 ABAP Repository Team Provider (Developer Edition) 1.18.0 (com.sap.ide.ui5.team.feature.feature.group 1.18.0)
  Missing requirement: SAPUI5 ABAP Repository Team Provider (Developer Edition) 1.18.0 (com.sap.ide.ui5.team.feature.feature.group 1.18.0) requires 'com.sap.adt.tools.base.devedition.feature.group 2.0.0' but it could not be found"

Comment: Have you tried https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/juno as updatesite? It gives you everything you need.

Comment: Yes. Install from eclipse itself by adding the url to the repository.